# Is there a way to use a Django registered BaseSetting in a models save function?

Tags: python, django, google-maps, wagtail

I am overriding a model's save function to query Google's Geocoding API for the corresponding latitude/longitude coordinates to an address and save them to the model.

I have registered a BaseSetting in Django admin with my API keys, and would like to access this registered setting inside my models.py to avoid hard-coding an API key.

Handling it in the view is not an option given I would like to minimize the number of API calls.

Here's some demo code:

```py
class DropoffLocationPage(models.Model):
    templates = "locations/dropoff_location_page.html"
    dropoff_address = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
    dropoff_city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
    dropoff_state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False)
    dropoff_zip = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, null=False)
    dropoff_unit_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    dropoff_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    dropoff_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)

    def get_coordinates(address):
        ....
        return response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        address = str(self)
        location = get_coordinates(address)
        self.dropoff_latitude = location['lat']
        self.dropoff_longitude = location['lng']
        super(DropoffLocationPage, self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.dropoff_address + " " + self.dropoff_city + ", " + self.dropoff_state + " " + self.dropoff_zip + " " + self.dropoff_unit_number)



@register_setting
class GoogleAPISetting(BaseSetting):
    maps_api_key = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        help_text="Your Google Maps API Key"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a `GoogleAPISetting` instance in your save method using [the standard Django ORM methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects). The only slightly tricky detail comes if you're managing multiple sites within one Wagtail project, in which case there will be one setting object per site, and you need some way of deciding which one to retrieve. (Within a view function, this isn't an issue, because you can always fetch the settings object corresponding to the current request using `GoogleAPISetting.for_request`.)

In this case, that probably doesn't matter, because even if you do have more than one site, there's no real reason to prefer one Google API key over another. So, you can just ask the ORM to return the first `GoogleAPISetting` object it finds:

```
def get_coordinates(address):
    setting_obj = GoogleAPISetting.objects.first()
    api_key = setting_obj.maps_api_key
    # ... do something with api_key ...
    return response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
```